# Blue screen error

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, memory, bsod

I have seen lot of questions for this topic. I tried to debug the issue according to available information but no sucess.

Let me brief, what I have tried.

I tried the machine with brand new Hard disk and I tried installing several operating systems.
Such as Linux mint, windows 7 and now windows 8 OS.

Today I tried with windows 8 OS and after few minutes I get the Blue screen error and machine was restarted. This time I haven't inatalled any drivers. Therefore, I assume that this issue doesn't come because of driver compatibility.

Then I guessed for the Ram and tried mem[image: memtest86]

But the tool doesn't detect any error. Please check above image.

Though this is image is not much useful I have attached it. this is taken when windows was restarted.
[image]

If you need any more information, please let me know.

I think I have checked for RAM, Hard Disk and Driver Compatibility now. Therefore, I am not sure, where I have to check any more. Do I need to change motherboard or is there any other thing I need to check?

I got following infomation from memory dump file.

```
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff80374b13038, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff88018547d20, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!MiCaptureProtectionFromProto+14
fffff803`74b13038 488b01          mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx]
```

Whatdo if I change my RAM?

Comment: It could still be a driver issue, I would update them all! But before, you need to find the cause. Event logs, programs like Who's crashed to view the crash dump file, Googling the error message BSOD gives will help.

Comment: previous time I had updated them using slim tool but I got the error

Comment: Did you analyse the crash dump file?

Comment: No how to do it where it is located? you mean C:\Windows\Minidump file? How to analyse this?

Comment: Well, why don't you re-read my first comment and answer when you've tried all suggestions! :)

Comment: upload the dmp files, so that we can look at them with a debugger